# Riak Save Update speed is too slow

Tags: linux, networking, riak

I Have 6 riak kv nodes, each VM have 30gb RAM VM, 8core CUP, 1gbps Ethernet bandwidth

```
CPU and IO utilization is not issue 
load average: 1.14, 1.26, 1.40 

root@E2ERiakNode1:~# iperf -c 172.16.98.55 -p 8087 
------------------------------------------------------------ 
Client connecting to 172.16.98.55, TCP port 8087 
TCP window size:  119 KByte (default) 
------------------------------------------------------------ 
[  3] local 172.16.97.177 port 35276 connected with 172.16.98.55 port 8087 
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth 
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  0.00   14754482724077531136 Bytes/sec 

Still Riak is working too slow, save and update in taking almost more 2 sec for each record 
We are not able to identify what is the issue. 

Is Ethernet speed is the issue? 

Please suggest 

Thanks
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: 1. What's the size of an object you store in Riak? 2. Did you try to run Riak benchmark to see the numbers for typical workloads on you setup? 3. Do you have siblings enabled? In general, having your Riak  version and configuration could help.